# Python foolproof min/max function with None

Tags: python, python-3.x, min, nonetype

I'm trying to design a custom min/max function that will always filter out every None from the inputs and if there is nothing else than None, it will also return None.
I have found several answers that were partial to my question on how to create an ideal function that can handle absolutely anything. Same as the original min/max functions.

This is what I have created so far:

```
def min_null(q, *args):
    if isinstance(q, Iterable):
        return min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, q)) if any(q) else None
    else:
        return min_null([q, *args])
```

can you see any way this could fail? Or how it could be improved?

I will be glad to any feedback :)

Comment: Can you clearly specify the expected possible inputs? Single values, iterables, any combination of the above? To note: if you need a function this flexible, it apparently means you're not always sure what data types you're dealing with, e.g. single values or iterables. That is an issue you might want to consider first. Why is it you don't know what you're dealing with?

Comment: well, I wanted to have one function and use it on tuples, lists, and also single variables, so that I don't have to look at what is in the data. I just know that all arguments in one call will be the same type and sometimes wrapped in list and sometimes not.

Comment: what if given iterable is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one failure case is `min_null([0, 0])`, which returns `None`, rather than what I would expect, which is `0`. This could be fixed in a variety of ways, but one would be to take out the `filter(lambda x: x is not None, q)` into a variable and then check it's length, rather than just checking for any truthy values.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use the min/max function with `key=` and a custom comparison object that treats `None` specially:

```
class Predicate:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __lt__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.item < other.item
        except TypeError:
            return False


print(min([0, 1, 2, None, 3, 4], key=Predicate))
print(min([None], key=Predicate))

print(max([0, 1, 2, 3, None, 4, 5], key=Predicate))
print(max([None], key=Predicate))
```

Output:

```
0
None
5
None
0
```

Do you have some more examples or tests around what the expected results should be?